# Htaccess redirecting not rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two domains - example.com and example.co. Both domains are on the same web hosting package and both document roots are 'public_html'

I want to rewrite any string after example.co (e.g. example.co/abc123) to https://www.example.com/page.php?url=TEXT-HERE

Here is my htaccess, but it seems to be redirecting instead of rewriting.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/page.php?code=$1
```

Comment: A change of domain name implies a redirect, since the browser must make a new request with a different HTTP host.

Comment: So does that mean that there's no way to rewrite the browser address?

Comment: I removed my answer below - can you describe your situation in more detail? You have a `.co` domain and a `.com` domain. You can't rewrite silently between them unless their files reside in the same virtualhost document root.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. I basically want to have domain.co/XXXXX to rewrite to http://www.domain.com/page.php?code=XXXXX. The XXXXX will be a five character code that should only forward on the .co domain.

Comment: Do the two domains reside in the same docroot filespace? If not, you can't rewrite across them without redirecting the browser (or implementing a GET proxy).

Comment: Both domains are in the same document root, they are both on my web hosting package. I currently have the .co domain parked to the .com domain if that helps.

Comment: Please add that information to your question above, in detail.  List the path of the doc root and the path of both domains in the file space. If the .co domain does not explicitly have its own directory, say that as well. We're starting to get the picture here, but you really need to spell it out for .htaccess & apache questions because it's hard to speculate on how directories are setup.

Comment: http to https cannot be silent/internal forward. It has to be an external redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question along with the comments, it seems you want to redirect any request from example.co with and without `www` to `page.php?code=anything after`, if that is right then you could try:

```
# match example.co with and without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co$ [NC]
# make sure we don't redirect page.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !page\.php
# internally redirect anything received to page.php as query string to code
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?code=$1 [L]
```

This will internally redirect so the user will still see the domain `example.co`.

Given that you still want to use HTTPS, in case its not already you can further use this, instead of the above rule:

```
# if it does not start with WWW we redirect to www.domain
# make sure the domain.co is enclosed by parenthesis like below
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(example\.co)$ [NC]
# we use this to make sure we are redirecting the right domain
# in case of multiple domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if HTTPS is not being used we force it to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# because we want to force it for this domain only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# and now we finally do the internal redirect
# match example.co, we don't need to match the www anymore
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co$ [NC]
# here we check if the file on the URL is page.php
# we don't want it redirect or we may fall into a loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !page\.php
# internally redirect anything received to page.php as query string to code
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?code=$1 [L]
```

Otherwise the rule you have should work just fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/page.php?code=$1 [R=302,L]
```

When the domain is different or the protocol is different it will yield a redirect like it or not that's how it works.

So if you try to redirect from domain A to domain B internally it will not work.

Same applies to sub domain to main domain or other domains or other sub domains.

To put it simple you can only redirect internally **from the domain in question to itself**.

Comment: @JasonLipo: Happy that your problem got solved however as per your question you wanted `https://www.example.com` in redirected URL. Just remember internal forward will not enforce https.

Comment: You're right. @Prix seemed to do the best with the situation and after reading all the comments, I realised that I couldn't redirect http to https - so I just added an SSL host to my .co domain so both domains had the same protocol. Thank you all.